# Authentication for "Classiq" quantum computing library failed

Tags: optimization, quantum-computing

I want to solve NP-hard combinatorial optimization problem using quantum optimization.In this regard, I am using "classiq" python library, which a high level API for making hardware compatible quantum circuits, with IBMQ backend.

To use "classiq", you have to first do the authentication of your machine (according to the official "classiq" website: https://docs.classiq.io/latest/getting-started/python-sdk/

Unfortunatly, whenever I ran the statement (classiq.authenticate()), I got runtime error as shown in the attached figure (with the full traceback).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmqe2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Classiq currently requires a license to use. This could be why the authentication fails.
A license can be acquired by contacting:
https://www.classiq.io/contact-us

Answer (score 1):

I think the Classiq API can definitely help you with your use case. But just like mentioned above you should contact Classiq for a license.